# DataFrames, df."example vector in the data()" raises a MethodError

Tags: dataframe, statistics, julia

So I have a dataframe df . CSV.read(...) and I have a column labeled 'Population in thousands (2017)'
and I used a command

```
df."Population in thousands (2017)"
```

This used to be what was working... but I installed some packages and created something and now I get THIS error when I input

```
df."Population in thousands (2017)"

    ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getproperty(::DataFrame, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  getproperty(::AbstractDataFrame, ::Symbol) at C:\Users\jerem\.julia\packages\DataFrames\S3ZFo\src\abstractdataframe\abstractdataframe.jl:295
  getproperty(::Any, ::Symbol) at Base.jl:33
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[10]:1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that this works on the current (at the time of writing) DataFrames release:

```
(jl_yo71eu) pkg> st
      Status `...\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_yo71eu\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.2.2

julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame("Population in thousands (2017)" => rand(5));

julia> df."Population in thousands (2017)"
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.8976467991472025
 0.32646068570785514
 0.5168819082429569
 0.8488198612708232
 0.27250141317576815
```

I'm assuming you're on an outdated version of DataFrames?

Edited to add following discussion in comments:

Bogumil can of course read your DataFrames version of the random folder name, so it appears you really are on an outdated version. You should do `add DataFrames@1.2` in the package manager to force an upgrade, which will tell you what packages in your current environment are holding you back.

Comment: Yes - OP is on 0.20.2 version of DataFrames.jl as can be seen from the \DataFrames\S3ZFo\ part of path in the error message.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838211/list-of-outdated-packages-in-julia

Comment: Since the OP mentions that this used to be working and stopped working after installing some packages, is it possible that one of those packages had a dependency on the lower version of DataFrames, and that's why it got downgraded? If so, how should they check to see which package it is that's blocking DataFrames from being the latest version?

Comment: It can be related to DataFrames.jl only indirectly, see https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/11/package-version-restrictions.html for instructions.