# List of outdated packages in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there a way to list all outdated packages in Julia? An equivalent of `pip3 list --outdated` in Python.

I made a couple searches ([1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/), [2](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1.1/managing-packages/)), but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature is implemented for the upcoming Julia 1.8 release as the `--outdated` flag to the `status` command:

```
(v1) pkg> status
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1/Project.toml`
  [7876af07] Example v0.5.1

(v1) pkg> status --outdated
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1/Project.toml`
  [7876af07] Example v0.5.1 (<v0.5.3)
```

See https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/2284